# Using Object.assign to avoid redundancy in Typescript constructors

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript application where there is a lot of code like this:

```js
class Model {

  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
  prop3: string;

  constructor(input: ModelInput) {
    this.prop1 = input.prop1;
    this.prop2 = input.prop1;
    this.prop3 = input.prop1;
  }

}

type ModelInput = {
  prop1: string,
  prop2: string,
  prop3: string,
}
```

I'd like to remove some of the boilerplate, specifically by replacing the constructor assignments with:

```
Object.assign(this, input);
```

This guarantees that the input fields are set on the constructed instance. However, Typescript doesn't seem to recognize the effect of this. It complains:

```
Property 'prop{1,2,3}' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

Is there any way around this problem, or am I stuck repeating every property name in the constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To suppress the error, you could use [definite assignment assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions):

```
class ModelAssert {

  prop1!: string;
  prop2!: string;
  prop3!: string;

  constructor(input: ModelInput) {
      Object.assign(this, input);
  }

}
```

or [`declare` property modifers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier):

```
class ModelDeclare {

  declare prop1: string;
  declare prop2: string;
  declare prop3: string;

  constructor(input: ModelInput) {
      Object.assign(this, input);
  }

}
```

depending on how you want those properties to be emitted to JavaScript.  This is less work than manually copying everything, but still requires a declaration in your class for each property in the input.  Also note that if you actually forget to initialize properties, these techniques suppress the error (remove the `Object.assign()` line and you still get no warnings).

---

If you really don't want to make a declaration at all, you can a class factory function implemented with some [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) like this

```
function AssignCtor<T extends object>() {
    return class {
        constructor(t: T) {
            Object.assign(this, t)
        }
    } as { new(t: T): T }
}
```

and then use it to make constructors of the form "take a parameter of type `T` and return a value of type `T`".  So `Model` could be:

```
class Model extends AssignCtor<ModelInput>() {
    method() {
        console.log(this.prop1 + ", " + this.prop2 + ", " + this.prop3);
    }
}
```

And you can verify that it works:

```
const model = new Model({ prop1: "hi", prop2: "okay", prop3: "bye" });
model.method(); // hi, okay, bye
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyD2ATApiAglZAnALtA3gFCHSnQAOW85AjAIQBc0EOWAlgHYDmA3CWZWoAmRs1ade-UoPIBmUS3bc+U6MHgdFAV2A54WABSdyWnEwQoQASQ4mcASgKqy0APIAjAFbJdAOkgQbFwcBjgAFmwQADTQxqb2fC4AvsQphKABcEioACI+4FjITqooGYUUVLRMihKJZKUFRTJC1eLKJflg5TKyrUqSquqarDp6hnFmWZY2do5ELi4e3n4BQSHhkTETCappaYQ4AJ7kRRaoM6bQALxOLjI0fRJRqs2P3M93lb1i-c9pAGZaDi6NgaaAYQLBADCYwAPAAVaDIAAeOGQHEQMHgXh8OAAfAY5tBVIUcFosBw1OAoLcFqQhtpdPpQkx4XNnHS3DiVlA1qEItFoA4OaQUsloJACNAOMgAO4s6Bs1nQFJpDI0s4gJGo9GY8G86FwzUXfGE2mkAC2yHCSDN805DPgIGQvhA8C4-Mivnu0AA1NAAEQxAN+oUC72VIShoOB0MbCAR6iyHbJQhqjQsaAW7Jam4y2VTVAGfAVagPQMRGOvQPwADWYEOVa+TAD7kOyBDSR22csvitNsQhJ40AA9CPoBEYnWGzE28ggA)